# How to setup a wordpress blog in Two or more languages?

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I would like to setup-install, wordpress and have a web site in two languages. Any ideas?

Can't find any solutions, most of the answers are like 4 years old...and they all talk about some old plugins.

Forget to mentioned that I have version 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found it http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/installation-guide/ and it works great. I don't know if I should remove the QA.

Comment: Leave your question here, and accept your answer to it (if you feel your answer is the best answer for your question). This will help other people who want to set up a multilingual wordpress blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WPML](http://wpml.org/), Wordpress Multilanguage. Avaible from within WordPress "Add New Plugin"

It offers a PRO version, where you can have your post translated by a professional translator. No need to create a separate user for yoyr blog.